# Gmaps style download from GCP

Tags: android, json, google-maps, download

I worked and styled a map for my project using new styler available on GCP account ( cloud based )
All what I have is a mapID and I can access this with a gmap api key
My question :
Is any possibility to Download the map style as Json file ?
My Project is in Angular and we are trying to make a web app based on gmaps and my developers saying that it’s better to implement a Json file instead having this on cloud
Thanks

Comment: Can you open a feature request for this? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788012

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I just had a reply from gmaps  customer service and that said that the cloud gmap style cannot be downloaded from the cloud ,however we can use the old gmap styler and save a map style as JSON format and use this where is needed
Thanks again